# img tag in HTML not displaying anything

Tags: html, image

I am trying to put a image onto my HTML code, but it does not show anything

I have tried using full file paths for the src attribute and deleting the width attribute. This is my full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <title>Rattlesnake - Help</title>
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
     <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>

    </header>
   <main>
      <img src="file:///F:/Python/Rattlesnake/rattlesnake.org/Rattlesnake.png" alt="The Rattlesnake logo" width="200px" />
   </main>
   <footer>

   </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

styles.css, help.html(this file) and Rattlesnake.png are in the same folder.

for the img tag, I have also tried `<img="Rattlesnake.png" alt="The Rattlesnake logo" />`
I know there are similar questones like mine, but none help me. Please help!
PS F: is a external drive

Comment: If all your files (.html, image) is in the same folder, then `<img src="rattlesnake.png">` would work. Check to see if its all in that same folder.

Answer (score 1):

Always avoid `src` paths starting with `file://` because they would only work on your computer and wouldn't work on a real website because the server's filesystem is different than yours.

The thing you "have also tried" has a small mistake which prevents it from working. Instead of:

```html
<img="Rattlesnake.png" alt="The Rattlesnake logo" />
```

It should be:

```html
<img src="Rattlesnake.png" alt="The Rattlesnake logo" />
```

You can only assign values to attributes in HTML, not the `img` word itself.